# Why am I getting this error in my Mongo query?

Tags: python, mongodb, database

```
Exception Type: OperationFailure at /
Exception Value: database error: point not in range
```

My code is this:

```
user_center = [ user_utm[1], user_utm[2] ]
user_radius = tools.milesToMeters(request.session['browser_distance'])

results = db.datasets.find({"test_set":"g2", "loc_utm": {"$within": {"$center" : [ user_center, user_radius ] }}});
```

For my Mongo query, I did this:

```
db.datasets.ensureIndex({"loc_utm":"2d"}, {"min":-999999999999, "max":99999999999 } );
```

My user_center and user_radius is this, when I printed it out:

```
[553068.42444848095, 4181244.9741927907]
16093.44
```

All my documents in my mongo collection have a UTM very similar to the user_center, so it should get the query. But, instead of returning the documents, I get this weird error.

Comment: Can you debug `user_center` and `user_radius`? What is the output value?

Comment: the output value is this:  [553068.42444848095, 4181244.9741927907]
and 16093.44

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run Mongodb Version 1.4.0/1.5.0  you should upgrade to 1.5.2 where that kind of  issue [has been fixed](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-994).

Comment: I'm getting this on MongoDB 1.8.3